# Need help getting PHP project to work on my wampserver

Tags: php, css, wamp, wampserver

This is my first time trying to use wamp and I'm having trouble viewing my php project. I know the code works just fine (because it is a copy of currently live site). Basically when I try to view the site on my localhost only the index.php file loads and the image folder. No css folders/files are loading. The links work, so I can navigate my site, but no css.

My project folder is inside the www folder in my localhost. See below my project is called movies. 
C:\wamp64\www\movies

When I go to view it at - http://localhost/movies/ , it displays only the html. When I view the sources tab in the console it shows the localhost/movies and inside movies an image folder and index, there should be many other folders including CSS and PHP folder called process.

Answer (score 0):

If you saved the **Webpage** by **CTRL+S** the sources to your wamp dir then maybe it didn't download all sources.

I suppose you are using Windows and maybe chrome or firefox. Inspect Element the page you are currently trying to view and find sources `.CSS|.JS|.JPG` in console then navigate to the file and see if it's working like `http:/localhost/assets/js/something.css`.

Remember all your files should be inside **www** folder because it is the root dir accessible for server.

If you are using `<?` (short open tag) then for Wamp, Left click on wamp, Hover on PHP then hover over PHP Settings, find "short open tag" and finally Click it. Restart Wamp Server.

Comment: Hi, all files are located in 'movies' folder which is located in the www folder. Also, I did inspect/view source and although I don't see the folders in the console I can navigate to them. For example even though the console doesn't have the css file there I can still navigate to css/style.css folder. It displays all the css code in the browser. I did CTRL+C CTRL+S the project to the www folder, but I can open the copied folder in my editor and everything is there.

Comment: Are you using an .htaccess file? maybe you are writing / as movies in .htaccess.

Also inside Console click on Elments, find a file and the open it in new tab check if it's accessable

Like this!

https://serving.photos.photobox.com/46119550a9614b85748fdcc36d8ad1eab366ecf396d6b3b187662564032ddf1afa339a4a.jpg

Comment: When I right click and view source on index.html

Comment: Developer Tools... CTRL+SHIFT+I or RIght Click and Inspect Elements. Or in view source find css file and try to open in in new window!

Comment: Sorry as I was typing the response above I found out the issue. It was my php code.My code was on webfaction hosting before and they don't require all of your php code to start like this <?php ?> , however wampserver does. I don't suppose you know how to adjust this somewhere so I don't have to comb through all files and change the  '<?' to '<?php'?

Comment: Instead of changing all tags from <? (short open tag) to <?php... Left click on wamp, Hover on PHP then hover over PHP Settings, find "short open tag" and finally Click it. Restart Wamp Server. Hope this Helps.

This is the example 
https://ibb.co/0K1RY4K

Comment: @C0deB0untyHunter That's a bad idea. PHP voted to deprecate `<?` in PHP 7.4. https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags

Comment: @ceejayoz He's using wamp maybe to test so as long as he wants to be able to use his current project i think it's okay because he's testing Local. Though if it's going live on site then yes it's a bad idea and if server is managed by an admin who can update PHP version or so then it's worst idea.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this might be due to the links. If your website is `example.com` and you link to an image `/directory/file.jpg`, the browser will request domain+uri -> `example.com/directory/file.jpg` and it works fine.

You run in a directory called `movies` and you access it via `localhost/movies/`. You expect that the browser used `localhost/movies/directory/file.jpg`, but it's not. It's domain+uri -> `localhost/directory/file.jpg`. As you can see, "/movies" is missing from it, thus it's not finding the file.

---

There are a few possible solutions. The best one is to add alocal test domain in your vhost file. You can do this by clicking the wamp logo -> 'your virtual hosts' -> 'virtual host management'.  This solution is a bit more difficult and might require some more research, but is the long term best solution.

- The first input is your website, eg `movies.test`.
- The second is the path, which is c:/wamp64/www/movies/ (or where-ever you have wamp).
- Then click start and restart wamp.

You can also set a base path in you html header.

```
<base href="/localhost/movies" >
```

And you could also link to your files relative

```
<img src="./images/file.jpg" />
```

These last two are easier, but require different values local vs on your production server. That works annoyingly if you have to keep updating it.